# How should I manage "reverting" a branch done with bookmarks in mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I have an open source project on bitbucket. Recently, I've been working on an experimental branch which I (for whatever reason) didn't make an actual branch for. Instead what I did was use bookmarks.

So I made two bookmarks at the same revision

- test --the new code I worked on that should now be abandoned(due to an experiment failure)
- main -- the stable old code that works

I worked in test. I also pushed from test to my server, which ended up switching the `tip` tag to the new unstable code, when I really would've rather it stayed at main. I "switched" back to the main bookmark by doing a `hg update main` and then committing an insignificant change. So, I pushed this with `hg push -f` and now my source control is "correct" on the server.

I know that there should be a cleaner way to "switch" branches. What should I do in the future for this kind of operation?

Comment: @MarkBooth I didn't realize that. Voted to close and marked for moderator attention to speed up the process

Answer (score 1):

`tip` is not a widely useful concept in a repository which has branches of any kind. Whether you are using bookmarks, named branches, or anonymous branches, `tip` always means the most recent commit on any branch, which is rarely something you care about. The real solution to your problem is to stop worrying about the `tip`!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, since you are switching (without quotes) branches, even if they are not named branches, they are still branches when you use bookmarks.

The mistake you had was an honest mistake and I see no way of having Mercurial protect you from doing that again with bookmarks (marking the same rev with different bookmarks and committing with the wrong one). What I can tell you though is how to do **private local branching with Mercurial**, and this way you can avoid having the consequences you just had:

## You use named branches and phases

**[Mercurial Phases](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Phases)** are really sweet, let me explain them real quick. You can mark revisions to three special states called phases, and these are: secret, draft and public.

1. **secret**: Don't get pushed. Can be modified through history editing.
2. **draft**: Get pushed. Can be modified through history editing. This is the default state of any revision.
3. **public**: Get pushed. Will issue a warning when using history editting extensions on them (strip, rebase, histedit,...).

As mentioned, all local revisions are ***draft* by default, when you push them, they become *public***. You can use the `hg phase` command to mark revisions to a particular phase, but if you are going from #3 to #2, or from #2 to #1 (according to the previous numbering), you need the -f argument to force the change, this is:

secret --> draft --> public

To go to the left you need to use --force or -f.

Here is what you do:

```
hg branch experiment
hg commit -m "Opening experimental branch" //say this creates revision 123
hg phase -sf tip                           //s is for secret, f is for force
//... hack hack hack
hg commit -m "Uh oh screwed up here"
hg push                                    //no secret revisions are pushed
```

Now, you can just abandon that branch and leave it like so, it wont ever get pushed. Forget about it and even just close it so that it wont bother you when you list your branches. It won't get pushed it won't get listed, so just don't worry about it.

However, if you have OCD, just strip (`hg strip`) the branch at the commit where the branch was opened, and it is gone:

```
hg strip 123
```

If you have an already existing branch, you can phase several revisions at once like this:

```
hg phase <start revision>::<end revision> -sf
```

To make your secret branch draft or public, just phase the latest revision to those phases:

```
hg phase -d tip    //assuming you are in the experiment branch
```

Then push, and the branch will become public.

Mercurial has been increasingly becoming better at history modification without changing it's general philosophy of discouraging just that. Phases are meant to protect you from accidental history modification as well as from sharing what you don't mean to.

## How *I* use bookmarks

Personally, I use bookmarks for debugging and for when I want to try 2 different ways of doing one thing. **To me, bookmarks are useful when you want to do anonymous branches** (update to a previous revision, commit and fork the history) but want to keep things intelligible.

Comment: I think the problem is I don't really know which way to branch in Mercurial as their seems to be 3 ways (cloning, actual branches, and bookmarks).. I think this sounds like a good plan for future things like this though

Comment: @Earlz They are all branches if you look at the DAG, what you call actual branches are just named branches. Also, don't "clone to branch", it is just... there are better ways, even when that one is easy to revert.